# Anyone know of algorithm for compairing real planar graphs? (for OCR)

Tags: computer-science, pattern-recognition

[image]

The picture pretty much explains it.  I will have a collection of line segment graphs to compare against and it's okay if it's $O(n)$ here because the set is the ASCII set or smaller .

I was thinking the algorithm would try to lay the $ in (1) with the symbols in (2), adding up total number of length change, angle change, segment addition / deletions.  This is the minimum number of ops to convert one set of line segments to another, intuitively.

Any other ideas?

Comment: [This paper](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/BMP-shape.pdf) describes a nice method for comparing shapes from scattered points you may be interested in. Basically they match points between two shapes using the Hungarian algorithm, then fit a transform between the matched points using thin-plate splines (as well as affine transforms). The parameters of the fitted transform characterize the similarity between the two shapes.